# UBUNTU 12.04 LTS - Dell Vostro 3446 audio and wifi (Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565) not working after update

Tags: 12.04, wireless, sound

I bought a new Dell Vostro 3446. everything was working fine till I was asked to update the Ubuntu package 12.04 LTS. Now my audio is completely *silent* and wifi network is *gone*. Can anyone please help me to fix it?

- [audio details](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=adcaad086bc47c46a1aa2b0430c5b2cb7a0ad048)

`lspci -nnk | grep -A 2 -F -e Audio -e Network`:

```
    00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. To make your question and its answer findable by the IDs of the affected devices, can you please [edit] your question and include the the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A 2 -F -e Audio -e Network` instead of plain `lspci` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED BASED ON UPDATED INFORMATION

Your wifi card seems have trouble with 12.04 kernel and you may need to compile kernel yourself. This is based on ubuntu forum thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044

I suggest try to upgrade your kernel to 12.04 HWE (Hardware Enablement Stack - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), use this command in console/terminal to upgrade kernel and x11 to trusty hardware stack.

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty`

After that, restart your laptop, and then use this command to check your current kernel version:

`uname -a`

Trusty use kernel version 3.13++.
Precise use kernel version 3.2 / 3.5 / 3.8.

If you decide to use HWE and sometimes later want to upgrade your ubuntu, you are suggested to skip normal version and go upgrade directly to the next LTS (14.04). HWE may exhibit problem when upgraded to non-LTS release.

Comment: I run the command alsamixer...i got this message "This sound device does not have any controls. "

Comment: i have edited my answer above pls check the output of lspci

Comment: Your wifi card seems a bit troublesome with 12.04 kernel. I suggest trying upgrade your kernel to check if the problem goest away, look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

As for audio, is seems analog output is detected after hdmi output. Rearrange kernel modprobe may help with this. But try to upgrade your kernel first.

Comment: I am a newbie in Ubuntu....pls keep patience with me...in the link which u hv provided do i need to run commands under Trusty and Precise to update the kernel?

Comment: I've updated my answer, i hope your problem solved by HWE.